# Xlwings - Referencing saved range and appending additional values

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I am a pretty inexperienced programmer and have been trying to practice some basics in Xlwings, a Python library that works with Excel. I am working in 2.7.

I have made a small program with GUI that allows you to simply add entries down a column in Excel. I noticed immediately upon trying my program that it overwrites the previously saved values down the column. I am completely lost in figuring out a workable solution on how to start with a list featuring the range, and then continuing to append to it.

```
from Tkinter import *
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

root = Tk()
wb = Workbook()

e1 = Entry()
e1.grid(row=1, column=2)

participant_list = [] 
"""I realize starting with an empty list will clear the range every time I
run the script, but am not sure what the correct solution should be."""

def pressed_button():

    entry = e1.get()
    e1.delete(0, END) # clear the entry widget
    temp = []
    temp.append(entry)
    participant_list.append(temp)
    Range('A1').value = participant_list
    print participant_list # just to test

b1 = Button(text="Add Participant", command=pressed_button)
b1.grid(row=2, column=2)

mainloop()
```

Any help in walking me through a solution would be greatly appreciated! I've tried a few different things, but am too embarrassed to put them in my demo code ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you could either read in your data first and assign it to `participant_list` or you could find out the last used cell in that column: E.g. if there are no empty rows, something like

```
rng = Range('A1').vertical.last_cell
...
Range((rng.row + 1, rng.column)).value = participant_list
```

could work.

Comment: Thank you! I must not have read the documentation well enough, as I did not realize there was a last.cell function.